# how to see spaces in data when selecting with mysql command line client

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i see spaces in String when using select with the sql-command-line-client?

What i mean is the following. you have three lines.
1, 2 and 3 Spaces.
You don't have a chance see the number of spaces.

```
create table foo(bar varchar(8));
insert into foo values(" "),("  "), ("   ");

select * from foo\g
+------+
| bar  |
+------+
|      |
|      |
|      |
+------+

mysql> select * from foo\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
bar:  
*************************** 2. row ***************************
bar:   
*************************** 3. row ***************************
bar:    
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

The only option i came up with is:

```
mysql> select bar, hex(bar) from foo;
+------+----------+
| bar  | hex(bar) |
+------+----------+
|      | 20       |
|      | 2020     |
|      | 202020   |
+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Something like var_export in php would be nice.

Comment: How about adding on some pre and post characters? `select bar, '>'+bar+'<' from foo`

Comment: i also thought of this. bit in mysql it's not very convenient: "concat('>', bar, '<')" and the string won't get ecsaped properly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears there is a string-function `QUOTE` (Escape the argument for use in an SQL statement) wich works really nice.

```
-- to add another tricky example
mysql> insert into foo values(" \" ' "), ("''");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select bar, quote(bar) from foo;
+-------+------------+
| bar   | quote(bar) |
+-------+------------+
|       | ' '        |
|       | '  '       |
|       | '   '      |
|  " '  | ' " \' '   |
| ''    | '\'\''     |
+-------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may replace spaces with some other characters in output like:

```
mysql> SELECT REPLACE('   ', ' ', '|');

+--------------------------+
| REPLACE('   ', ' ', '|') |
+--------------------------+
| |||                      |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is just about displaying the space then  you'll need to encode the string before you store it. If it's about comparison then you'll find that leading strings (before a non space) are preserved while trailing are not. See more here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455147/comparing-strings-with-one-having-empty-spaces-before-while-the-other-does-not)

Answer (score 0):

How about using String `LENGTH()` to get a similar result to `php` `var_export()`

```
SELECT bar, LENGTH(bar) FROM foo;
```

Comment: this may work for short strings, but what about long strings (for example 325 chars)? again you could not determine where the string ends.